# What is the probability that a Poisson random variable is prime?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, prime-numbers

Let $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$, and let $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Consider the quantity $Q(\lambda,k) = P\left( X+k \in Primes\right)$. Obviously $0 < Q(\lambda,k) < 1$.

How does $Q(\lambda,k)$ behave with respect to $\lambda$ and $k$?

For example, is there any asymptotic behavior as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$?

Is $Q(\lambda,k)$ sensitive to the value of $k$ when $\lambda$ is large enough?

Comment: Asymptotically I'd expect $Q(\lambda, 0)$ to be "the probability that a number near $\lambda$ is prime", i. e. about $1/\log \lambda$.

Comment: @ualex: please reopen your question so that we can continue the discussion.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Sure. I re-opened it.

Comment: Here's a similar problem but with a finite range of the parameter: 1) what is the probability w(a) that a geometrically distributed variable (k ~ (1-a) a^k, k=0,1,2,... ) is a prime number? 2) what is the maximum value of w(a) and at which a is it attained?

Answer (score 7):

The probability in question is given by the limit of the partial sum up to the n-th prime by (I have replaced lambda by "a" for the convenience of Mathematica)

```
p[n_, a_] := Exp[-a] Sum[a^Prime[k]/Prime[k]! , {k, 1, n}]
```

In order to have a requested accuracy of to some value amax we need a definite number of terms n.

We could write for instance

```
With[{a = 50}, 
 Table[1 - p[k + 1, a] p[k,a// N, {k, 20, 30}]]

(* {-0.00205371, -0.00016001, -0.0000226721, -8.46669*10^-7, -5.67576*10^-9, \
-3.62011*10^-10, -8.61438*10^-11, -4.34702*10^-12, -9.2317*10^-13, \
-3.73379*10^-14, -1.68778*10^-19} *)
```

In the following we plot some graphs and adjust n by hand to a value beyond which we don't see any change in the graph.

[image]
(* 141208_plot _n12.jpg *)

[image]
(* 141208_plot_n21 *)

[image]
(* 141208_plot _n50.jpg *)

[image]
(* 141208_plot _n100.jpg *)

An interesting nontrivial curve results, and it seems that there is a certain limiting region `for a>>1` about p(a>>1) ~= 0.15.

**EDIT #1 Asymptotic behaviour**

In order to estimate the asymptotiv behaviour of the probabality for large "a" we consider two aspects

(1) the numer of primes below n is approximately given by g(n) = n/log(n)
(2) the Poission Distribution w(a,k) = Exp(-a) a^k/k! for a>>1 is approximately a normal distribution with mean a and deviation roughly +-Sqrt(a)

Hence the main contribution to the sum defining the probability comes from primes between a-Sqrt(a) and a+Sqrt(a). Their number is approximately g(a+Sqrt(a)- g(a-Sqrt(a)).
Dividing this by the number of natural numbers in this interval, 2 Sqrt(a) gives the probability estimate as

```
p(a>>1) ~= 1/(2 Sqrt(a))( (a+Sqrt(a))/Log(a+Sqrt(a)) -(a-Sqrt(a))/Log(a-Sqrt(a)) )
```

Numerical values are

```
{h[10], h[50], h[100], h[400]} = {0.245097, 0.190413, 0.170051, 0.139057}
```

They are in fairly good agreement with the values in the graphs.
For very large "a" we find

```
p(a->oo) = 1/Log(a)
```

as expected by Michael Lugo without proof today in his comment.

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Nicely done. Basically, you have a one-liner solution, to arbitrary $n$. And `p[100,1] //N` returns 0.248392 ... I would just present the solution as a function of $\lambda$, without giving the plotting code, as the latter detracts from legibility, and is not of general interest in this forum.

Comment: @wolfies: Plot[] removed. BTW: I wonder if I have missed some rules of this forum, as there seems to be an inverse relation between information provided in answers and points assigned to them?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about voting: the flock can be wary of upvoting a newcomer, while long-timers attract a following. P.S. I would also suggest deleting your 1st and 3rd plots, as they are nested by the other two plots.

Comment: +1. This answer has more content than tons of other upvoted ones

Answer (score 4):

$$e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{\lambda^j}{j!} I_{prime}(j+k)$$
where $I_{prime}(n) = 1$ if $n$ is prime, $0$ otherwise.  If you're expecting a closed form for this, think again.

Comment: I did not expect an answer along the line of $1/\pi$. I expected some interesting discussion of how this probability might behave. How does $\lambda$ affect it? How sensitive it is to the value of $k$?

Answer (score 3):

Robert Israel gave a general answer, but you asked for more. Consider the special case $\lambda=1,\ k=0.$ This gives the constant

> 0.24839162...

which is related to sequence [A100124](https://oeis.org/A100124) in the OEIS.

Comment: $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{j!} I_{prime}(j) = 0.671 ...$. The required probability (when $\lambda = 1$) is $\frac{0.671...}{e}  = 0.2483..$, as per the solution of Wolfgang Hintze in _Mathematica_.

Comment: @wolfies: Good catch -- thanks! I fixed it.