# The probability of getting a prime number from a Poisson random draw

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

I know the probability of getting an odd number from a Poisson random draw of rate $\lambda$ is $\frac{1+e^{-2\lambda}}{2}$, what I'm interested in is the probability of getting a prime number from a Poisson random draw. Is there a way to find the closed-form solution to this problem or there's no hope? thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the probability that a Poisson random variable is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055438/what-is-the-probability-that-a-poisson-random-variable-is-prime)

Comment: Hmmm, I think my question is the case for $Q(\lambda,0)$ from that post? , So the answer is $\frac{1}{\text{log}\lambda}$?

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused with this question, so I can't really judge whether that post answer my question or not @Golden_Ratio